# Can't access standard asset MotionBlur class in script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am attempting to make a simple horror game in Unity. Unfortunately when I try to assign a variable to MotionBlur like this;

```
private var mBlur : MotionBlur;
```

I am presented with the following error...

```
BCE0018: The name 'MotionBlur' does not denote a valid type ('not found').
Did you mean 'UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects.MotionBlur'?
```

Yet I have the image effects/Standard assets installed. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Perhaps you need a `using` or `import` directive for `UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects` first, before you can reference `MotionBlur`? Alternatively, use the suggested `UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects.MotionBlur`.

Comment: Thank you VERY much - Using the "import UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;' has worked. this has saved me a lot of time! Thank you!!!

Comment: Great, I'm glad this solved your problem so quick! I'll add an answer so we can mark this question as resolved - feel free to accept it when you've got the chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the appropriate library before you can reference classes defined in it. In this case, before using `MotionBlur` you would need to add:

```
import UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;
```

An alternative is to always reference `MotionBlur` as `UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects.MotionBlur` everywhere in your code - though this isn't my recommendation here, given how verbose it is. (It does become useful if you ever end up with two libraries that define classes using the same name, however.)